# get device name connected to port /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: python, pyserial

Is there a way to get the device name connected to the serial port?

This code gives me just the name of the serial port. But I need the device name connected to it i.e. Nokia Phone

```
import serial
import time


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                     460800, 
                     timeout=5, 
                     xonxoff = False, 
                     rtscts = False, 
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
sere = ser.name
print (ser, sere)
```

I've been checking other possibilities like `gammu-detect` but I would like to have a self standing python script that does this operation. Is there a way to get it done with pyserial?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

But this is not strictly linked to serial port itself. It depends on the protocol the device is using.

In essential, you send some preset initial data to the device and it responds with manufacturer, name, model and version or some combination of these.

I am not sure whether this is standardized or not, you will have to search for it.

If it is standardized, it is most probably something like:

```
1. Open the port with 9600 baud rate
2. Send the request for info
3. Use info to reset the port etc.
```

I know that some programs do this. You can even hear old 56K modems reacting to the query when detection algorithm asks them who they are.

Now, you have to search whether this is a standard procedure or each device has its own.

If you are searching for phones, then very probably there is one for phone versions, perhaps each per OS like iOS, Symbian, Android, Windows *, ...

If you cannot find the protocol on the internet, then install virtual card for serial ports, perform man in the middle on looped ports to see what data is sent at initial communication with the phone application.

Note: Don't watch for data when connecting to the internet i.e. using the phone as a modem. You will see only AT&T protocol, which wouldn't help you much.

If you want to see how it works universally, use same technique with virtual serial card but when new device wizard detects for new hardware.

P.S. I found something!

Try sending:

```
"\x02S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03"
```

You should get back some data containing numeric identifier of a device. Like serial number.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I think what you've send me goes in the right direction, but ´ser.write('\x02S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03')´ just gives me the number 7. However its the same one I get by sending the AT Command ´AT+CGMI´ which supposed to give me the manufacturer name of the device. Do I need somehow to wait for the response of the device?

Comment: The idea is to send the device some data. If it is wrong, then a device responds with an error code/message. If it is right, then you get the info or serial code. So what happens here is most probably that you are getting the error code. Using AT&T when phone is not in a modem mode won't do you any good. At least it shouldn't. Phone may receive AT&T out of the blue, but it will most probably return you just GPRS modem firmware version. Usually the phone needs to be put into GPRS mode either by command from port or manually. (like iPhone).

Comment: Also, make sure you are using correct baud rate. If baud rate is wrong, the device will receive some nonsense and perceive it as an error. The returned value will also be a nonsense. Returned 7 indicates that both my string and the AT&T command are received as an error, but whether it is an actual error or the baud rate is wrong is to be checked. If 7 is actually binary 55 (ord("7")), then it is possible that 55 means something like (this device is a phone). But it is most probably an error.

Comment: Try putting your phone in GPRS/GSM mode and send AT&T to it. Not only AT+*, but try to call some number. Or send a SMS to yourself. If this works, then baud rate is most probably right. Unless they differ per protocol. Oh, and yes, you actually DO NOT have to wait. I mean, you have to receive the response, but you also have to set timeouts to the opened port, at least when detecting devices, so that if you hit a device that doesn't answer to your nonsensible message you can just close the port and go on checking.

Comment: Writing SMS works fine, which means that the baudrate works well. However, I don't get how to receive a response from the device...

Comment: And when you are in GPRS modem mode, do you get the model by the AT command you wrote above? You should.

Answer (score 1):

Now things work well! I had to type the .read command. Here the solution:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                     460800, 
                     timeout=5, 
                     xonxoff = False, 
                     rtscts = False, 
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
#s = input('Enter AT command --> ')
#print ('AT command = ' + s)
ser.write(bytes('AT+CGMI' + '\r\n'))
ser.timeout = 1
response = ser.read(999)
print(response)
ser.close()
```